# jQuery: How to sync table cell/row heights

Tags: jquery, css-tables

How can I synchronize the row-heights of two tables (which makes them look like ONE table if placed next to each other)?
Here's a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2B8sy/
Works fine in Firefox - doesn't work in Chrome or IE.

[image]

Problem is, passing jQuerys `.height()` of a cell to another cells `.height()` makes the cells not equal in height in Chrome and IE - works fine in Firefox though.

[image]

As you can see in the Fiddle, the first rows are always 2 pixels too short. Happens to all rows. This is for Chrome and IE10. Everything is fine in Firefox.

Why does `element.height(otherElement.height());` not make them equal in height?
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2B8sy/

I also tried window.getComputedStyle, but I got the same results there.

Comment: Can we see the CSS as well?

Comment: of course. I updated the post. These are the basic CSS definitions.

Comment: here's a clean JS fiddle with the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/2B8sy/

I deleted my example usecase in favor of JSFiddle as it is much cleaner and better to work with

Comment: thanks for the JSFiddle, that was perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've cracked this in Chrome.  http://jsfiddle.net/2B8sy/5/

The issue was with the measuring of the td height.  I've updated the CSS for the td as below:

```
table td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This extra code tells the browser to include padding and margins inside the height and width measurements, so you don't get discrepancies when working with these elements.

I suspect Chrome and the other failing browsers were not consistent in their read and set of this property.

Comment: You can also fix this by using the height of the `tr`, and not the `td` - which is what i did before i saw your answer. Nice.

Comment: @Sumit - yeah, I guess that would work as the tr height would already have covered the (td height) + (td border).